# Expand all data table entries at once in VuetifyJS/VueJS

Tags: vuetify.js

How to expand **all** entries of this [VuetifyJS](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-expand)/VueJS data table example at once and not only one at the time?

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      hide-actions
      item-key="name"
      expand
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td> 
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>Peek-a-boo!</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here is an example for a single expand:

> `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEWNxE?&editors=101#`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an [open-issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2890) with regards to this feature, make sure to follow it and get notified when it's resolved.

---

**Temporary solution** by @zikeji follows:

Add reference to the table:

```
<v-data-table ref="dTable">
```

Expand rows manually when component loads:

```
mounted() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.desserts.length; i += 1) {
        const item = this.desserts[i];
        this.$set(this.$refs.dTable.expanded, item.name, true);
    }
},
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEJeVo)

Comment: Just so you know, this goes against VueJS conventions because you are setting the state of a child from the parent. You could instead extend the component and add a watcher and a prop that sets these values

Comment: @MiguelCoder Thank you for clarification. However, it's noted that this is a temporary workaround, and the feature will be implemented, probably soon(tm) because it seems resolved already, just not pushed live.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a temporary solution. However, I think it's important to enforce VueJS paradigms because it helps the programmer to understand how components are supposed to communicate. It also allows for  reusability of code.

Comment: @MiguelCoder Agree. Perhaps it's good to note it, thanks. However, in this case I'd still prefer to have less stuff to revert once this feature is implemented, and it appears it's going to happen soon.

Comment: All you would have to do is delete the file and maybe change the name of the prop. It's easier than having to go through your code and try to remember where you added that logic to expand the table.

Answer (score 7):

in Veutify v2.1.13

Just copied data to `expanded` from `desserts`on click.

```
  methods: {
    expandAll: function() {
      console.log("All expanded.");
      this.$data.expanded = this.$data.desserts;
    },
    collapseAll: function() {
      console.log("All collapsed.");
      this.$data.expanded = [];
    }
  },
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/snize/pen/GRggXwp?editors=1011)

Comment: Not a big fan of this, but seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend the component instead and set the values as such.

MyVDataTable.vue

```
<script>

import VDataTable from 'vuetify/src/components/VDataTable'
export default {
    extends: VDataTable,
    props: ['deserts'],
    mounted () {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.desserts.length; i += 1) {
            const item = this.desserts[i];
            this.$set(this.expanded, item.name, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would replace your VDataTable with this one.

Comment: I don't understand what headersLength does exactly. I tried your example but it did change anything. Also, I need to use the headers so I can't hide them. Here is an codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEWNxE?&editors=101# If you click an entry it expands. I need to expand  all. Any ideas how to archive that?

Comment: I will change my answer

Answer (score 0):

For me the above and other solutions found on google were not working. So i created another approach.

To the row where you usually add your @click expand function you have to add a custom directive.

for example `v-open`

and pass your props.

```
 <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded" v-open="props">
```

then inside your component

```
directives: {
            open: {
                // directive definition
                bind: function (el,binding) {
                    //only the first row
                    if( binding.value.index === 0){
                        binding.value.expanded = true
                    }
                    //or all rows
                    //binding.value.expanded = true
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
expanded.sync

```
 <v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :expanded.sync="desserts"
  hide-actions
  item-key="name"
  expand
>
```